# How to make Highcharts to use all the colours when replotting? (it is repeating colours unnecessarily)

Tags: javascript, plot, highcharts, colors

I am rendering a chart using **Highcharts.js** library

```
 $('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
    ...
```

I have some checkboxes to select which series to plot. Depending which series I plot the first time, the colors will be different.

### How to reproduce

1. Go to the example: http://jsfiddle.net/1u98o3aq/1/
2. Select only "Tokyo" checkbox, click **plot**
3. Select "New york" checkbox, click **plot**
4. Select "Berlin" checkbox, click **plot**
5. ...

As you can see, it is not using all the colors, all of them are plotted in blue.

[image: jsfiddle example]

You can now unselect everything, plot. Then select everything, plot. The 4 series will remain all with the same color.

However, if you start (Run) the example again, and this time select everything and plot, now it is rendered correctly. Now you can unselect everything and go one by one. The colors are right.

If you select now only the 2nd and the 3rd series, the 2nd and 3rd colors will be used (no blue).

It is like Higcharts is caching for each series a color (which should not) and chosing wrongly (starting from color 0) when adding more series to be shown.

**Using custom colors does not solve the problem.**

Comment: I have used custom color and it solved problem for me: http://jsfiddle.net/1u98o3aq/2/ aren't you able to use custom colors in your chart?

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński If you add the colors to the series object, it will work fine. However, if you add a list of custom colors to the chart options, the problem will persist. However, if nobody comes up with a solution, I guess I can use your approach and dynamically asign the colors I want to the selected series. So thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is connected with how you are loading your series to your chart.

Right now, when you are loading the new chart, you are basing into previously drawn series (you are updating the series array).

To avoid the problem you have, you should be able to make copy of your array before you will load it into your chart:

```
lastSeries = $.extend(true, [], seriesSelection);
```

Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/1u98o3aq/3/

Comment: Thank you, this is a more satisfying solution that your comment in my question. However, just for other people visiting this question: I was creating a new array each time, and pushing the selected series from the old array into the new one. That did not work., but making a copy with `$.extend` does work.

Comment: you could write it in an even better way. instead of drawing the chart each time, just add the series to the existing chart.

Comment: Exactly Rahul, I was considering this approach in my example, but I have resigned because I wanted to show directly the problem why colours were not respected.